# How to match/capture a multiline substring in between a keyword and the next occurring empty line (or the string's end)?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, regex-group, multiline

I searched around and cannot find anything that could help me. I was hoping for some help.

The javascript code searches a body of text and finds a phrase then it should grab whole text after it finds it.

Works great on single line strings but not on multiple lines :(

Ideally I could get all colours listed in the same text box seperated by commas.

Like give me everything after "Colours affected" until we get to an empty line.
Is this possible?

https://jsfiddle.net/fenster89411/knrzpvta/3/ working example

```js
function extractInfo() {
  var text = document.getElementById('textarea').value
  text = text.split('\n')

  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i += 1) {
    if (text[i].includes('Scheduled Maintenance')) {
      var approverName = text[i].replace('Scheduled', '').trim();
      document.getElementById('approvername').value = approverName;
    }
    if (text[i].includes('Maintenance ID')) {
      var approverEmail = text[i].replace(/.*Maintenance ID\D*(\d*).*/, '$1').trim();
      document.getElementById('approveremail').value = approverEmail;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Information Extraction</title>
</head>
<body>

<textarea id="textarea" rows="20" cols="50">
Scheduled Maintenance 44445555666 - Multiple COLOURS Affected
Maintenance ID 444555666 
Colours affected

Yellow
Blue
Black
red
purple
</textarea>

<button onclick="extractInfo()">Extract Information</button>

<!-- Display extracted information -->
<div>
  <label for="approvername">Scheduled Maintenance Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="approvername" readonly>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="approveremail">Maintenance ID Email:</label>
  <input type="text" id="approveremail" readonly>
</div>


<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please add a working example to the snippet, as right now the question and goal is not clear at all. Can you please also take the time to format the questions so that they are more easily readable.

Comment: I am not able to run the code as is

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you want to get the text between "Components affected" and the next empty line, right? If that's the case, check out the documentation on string methods in MDN, like [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: Ive tidied it up - sorry this is all very new to me

Comment: The URL (https://jsfiddle.net/fenster89411/knrzpvta/3/-) doesn't work. The correct version is: https://jsfiddle.net/fenster89411/knrzpvta/3/  Edit the URL please.

Comment: I don`t get it? Your fiddle works? It puts the ID in the box below it but it is labelled email and there is no email in the text? Where do you want the colours listed? I would put all the possible colours in an array and search for matching colours in the text and output wherever with a , after each one, if that is what you want to achieve?

Comment: the next part I need is an extraction to a text box in the form , everything after 'Colours affected' which should be Yellow,Blue,Black,red,purple

Comment: Something like that ... [`/Colours\s+affected(?:\n+(?:(?:(.*?)(?:\n{2,}|\n$))|(.*)))/gs`](https://regex101.com/r/dKw9gG/1) ... which covers all these scenarios ... [scenario 2](https://regex101.com/r/dKw9gG/2), [scenario 3](https://regex101.com/r/dKw9gG/3), [scenario 4](https://regex101.com/r/dKw9gG/4), [scenario 5](https://regex101.com/r/dKw9gG/5).

Answer (score 0):

A regex which pretty much covers any possible valid scenario might look similar to the following one ...

```
const regXColors = /Colours\s+affected(?:\n+(?:(?:(.*?)(?:\n{2,}|\n$))|(.*)))/gs;
```

... and [its pattern gets explained at its playground page](https://regex101.com/r/dKw9gG/1).

In order to extract the intended result one would utilize [`RegExp.prototype.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) and its [result array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#using_exec) where one can access the values of the pattern's two [capturing groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups). Making partially use of the OP's original example code, an implementation could be achieved like follows ...

```js
function getAllAffectedColors(value) {
  const regXColors =
    // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/dKw9gG/1]
    /Colours\s+affected(?:\n+(?:(?:(.*?)(?:\n{2,}|\n$))|(.*)))/gs;

  const regXResult = regXColors.exec(value) ?? [];
  const colorValue = (regXResult[1] || regXResult[2]) ?? null;

  return (colorValue === null) ? [] : colorValue.split(/\n/);
}
function logAllAffectedColors() {
  const textValue = document.querySelector('#textarea').value;
  const colorList = getAllAffectedColors(textValue);

  console.clear();
  console.log({ colorList, colorString: colorList.join(', ') });
}
document
  .querySelector('button')
  .addEventListener('click', logAllAffectedColors);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
button { display: block; }
textarea { width: 40%; }
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; width: 57%; min-height: 100%; }
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" rows="11" cols="30">
Maintenance ID 444555666 
Colours affected


Yellow
Blue
Black
red
purple

</textarea>

<button>log all affected colors</button>
```